# Failed: Service for snap application thegloaming.alarumd

Tags: boot, nvidia, do-release-upgrade

Two days ago upgraded via command line my Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10

It's an old 2015 laptop. First two restarts were fine. But now fails with message:

> Failed to start Service for snap application thegloaming.alarumd. [
> 44.155799] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [IENGINE ] [ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device

Or view

[image: camera shot of error]